# Can't connect to mysql docker container from springboot docker container

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, containers, devops

I want to connect from the sprinboot container to the mysql container but i get this error:
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

I am using docker-compose.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  trips-db:
    image: "mysql"
    container_name: "trips-db"
    volumes:
        - newDatabase:/home/sharedData
    ports:
        - 49152:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=adham
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin

  trips-app:
    build: ./Wasalny_BE
    container_name: trips-app
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    links:
        - trips-db

volumes: 
  newDatabase:
```

This is my spring boot docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY target/wasalny-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://trips-db:49152/wslny?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= admin
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

I run using the following command form the terminal:

```
docker-compose up -d 
--force-recreate
```

Comment: MySQL normally listens on port 3306 and you need to use that port number in `spring.datasource.url`.  Connections between containers don't use or require `ports:`, they always use the standard port for the destination container.

Comment: I tried using the 3306 port after the image name in the spring.datasource.url but still it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

### Please create a docker network and attach it into the compose file.

#### Create a docker Network first like below.

docker network create ext-network

#### Add network settings into your yaml file as below and give a try

```
version: '3'
services:

  trips-db:
    image: "mysql"
    container_name: "trips-db"
    volumes:
        - newDatabase:/home/sharedData
    ports:
        - 49152:3306
    networks:
      - ext-network
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=adham
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin

  trips-app:
    build: ./Wasalny_BE
    container_name: trips-app
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - ext-network
    links:
        - trips-db
        
networks:
  ext-network:
    external: true

volumes: 
  newDatabase:
```